# C# Livecharts data input

Tags: c#, sql

I am taking data from an SQL database and then inputing into a `ChartValues<>` variable but the data always is empty. The input data is a number (numeric) from SQL Server.

I have converted it to `int`, `double`, `string` and then tried feeding that in the the `SeriesCollection` statements.

```cs
ChartValues<int> data1 = new ChartValues<int>();

SqlCommand d1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT " +
                                    "[Month]" +
                                    ",[Paid] " +
                                "FROM [LUC Payments] " +
                                "WHERE USER = @UserID " +
                                "and [LUC Type] = 'Residential' ");
d1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", ApplicationContent.User_name);
d1.Connection = con;
con.Open();
dr = d1.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        int.TryParse(d1.ToString(), out int b3);
        data1.Add(b3);
    }
}
dr.Close();
con.Close();

SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
{
    new LineSeries
    {
        Title = "Residential Payments",
        Values = new ChartValues<int> (data1),
        PointGeometry = DefaultGeometries.Circle,
        PointGeometrySize = 15
    }/*,
    new LineSeries
    {
        Title = "Commercial Payments",
        Values = new ChartValues<double> { 2, 2, 2, 2 ,2 },
        PointGeometry = DefaultGeometries.Triangle,
        PointGeometrySize = 15
    },
    new LineSeries
    {
        Title = "Other",
        Values = new ChartValues<double> { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 },
        PointGeometry = DefaultGeometries.Square,
        PointGeometrySize = 15
    }
    ,
    new LineSeries
    {
        Title = "Total Payments",
        Values = new ChartValues<double> { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
        PointGeometry = DefaultGeometries.Square,
        PointGeometrySize = 15
    }*/
};
```

Comment: First of all please make a constants string for that SQL request (`private const string ResPaymSQLReq = "SELECT [Month], [Paid] FROM [LUC Payments] WHERE USER = @UserID and [LUC Type] = 'Residential'");`)

Comment: What is the result of the query when you execute using a SQL client? Perhaps the value of `ApplicationContent.User_name` is not as expected.

Comment: @noobMan: How many records (`int`s) are there in `data1`?

Comment: one per month. So at them moment there are 2 records.